# Concatenate Strings for Dictionary:syntax error

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, syntax

The following code to conditionally concatenate strings for a dictionary seems to work up to the point where I try to place the concatenated result in the dictionary. Can anyone see the error?

```
 NSDictionary *jsonDictionary;
        NSString* dictString = @"@\"first\":first,@\"last"
                NSString *dictString2=dictString;
                if (date.length>0&&![date isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
//only include this key value pair if the value is not missing 
                    dictString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%s", dictString, "@\"date\":date"];

                }

                jsonDictionary = @{dictString2}; //syntax error. Says expected colon but that does not fix anything
```

Comment: you are seriously confused by dictionary literals (which are a compile-time thing) and parsing some text into a dictionary data structure.

Comment: Perhaps you should learn about `NSMutableDictionary`.

Comment: You seem to be missing a semicolon at the end of the second line.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for creating an `NSDictionary` using object literals is:

```
dictionary = @{key:value}
```

(and optionally, it can contain multiple key/value pairs separated by commas, but never mind that right now.)

Where "key" and "value" are both `NSObject`s.

Your line that is throwing the error only contains 1 thing. The contents of a the string in `dictString2` has nothing to do with it.

It looks to me like you are trying to build a `JSON` string manually. Don't do that. Use `NSJSONSerialization`. That class has a method `dataWithJSONObject` that takes an `NSObject` as input and returns `NSData` containing the `JSON` string. That's how you should be creating `JSON` output.

Comment: I am trying to build the contents of the dictionary manually to get around the pesky issue of values potentially being nil or null.  Yes it's a bit of a hack, but the alternatives all seem much worse.  Can you suggest a better way around the missing value issue?  Alternatively, how would I stick the right code into the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Creating an NSDictionary with values that may be null:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{
                       @"key" : value ?: [NSNull null],
                      };
```

When serializing a dictionary, `NSNull`s are translated to `null` in the JSON.

If you want to exclude such keys completely, instead of having them with a `null` value, you'll have to do more work.  The simplest is to use an `NSMutableDictionary` and test each value before adding it.